# Install PHP 7.1 on CentOS 8.3

Tags: centos, php

How to install PHP 7.1 on Centos 8.3?

`dnf module list php` returns PHP packages starting from 7.2 so I guess I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: See https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 7.1 is EOL and no longer supported. If you absolutely must have it, the only option left to you would be to try and build it from source.

[This](https://phpcodez.com/install-php-from-source-centos-linux/) is a decent guide to follow for building it from source - I quickly ran through it on a CentOS 8 VM and was able to get PHP compiled and installed, though I did notice a few warnings it barked about along the way, which could cause some unknown issues post-install. I had to add some additional installations at the install step, like so: `dnf autoconf libtool bison libxml2-devel bzip2-devel libcurl-devel libpng-devel libicu-devel gcc-c++ libmcrypt-devel libwebp-devel libjpeg-devel make freetype-devel httpd httpd-devel perl`.

I would highly recommend installing a newer, support version via Remi Repos. I followed [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-on-centos-8/) and was able to install 7.4 without issues. It also has 7.2 available as well, which depending on your needs for 7.1 may be an easier solution, though I believe 7.2 is unsupported now as well.

Comment: FYI https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2019/12/18/PHP-7.1-is-dead (so still available in "remi" repo, but, as you said,  should be avoided)

Comment: Indeed, thanks for that. Also: ITS YOU! :D